# How to implement less and greater than rules with decision table in drools?

Tags: drools

I would like to implement simple rules based on the less and greater values in drools using decision table.

It is easy enough to implement the rules in drl, for example:

```
rules "less than"
when Example(value < 10)
then 
    System.out.println("Less than 10")
end

rules "equals"
when Example(value = 10)
then 
    System.out.println("Equals 10")
end

rules "greater than"
when Example(value > 10)
then 
    System.out.println("Greater than 10")
end
```

But how can I translate it into decision table in drools? All the examples I have seen so far is to have the comparison done in condition cell. Is it even possible to do the comparison in value cell?

All example I had seen are in format of:

```
CONDITION                          |  ACTION
Example                            |
value                              |
-----------------------------------|-------------------------------------
10                                 |  System.out.println("equals to 10")
```

But that only applies to 1 rule, and doing the following totally has different meaning:

```
CONDITION  | CONDITION  | CONDITION  | ACTION
Example
value      | value > $1 | value < $1 |
-----------+------------+------------+----------------
10         | 10         | 10         | ???
```

Is even possible to do the following?

```
CONDITION                          |  ACTION
Example                            |
value                              |
-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------
10                                 |  System.out.println("equals to 10")
> 10                               |  System.out.println("greater than 10")
< 10                               |  System.out.println("less than 10")
```

What is the right way to implement these rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that I can achieve what I needed by putting just *$param* in the constraint field cell and put in the whole constraint in the value cells. So the decision table looks like this:

```
CONDITION                      | ACTION
Example                        |
$param                         | System.out.println("$param");
-------------------------------+-----------------------------------
value == 10                    | equals to 10
value > 10                     | greater than 10
value < 10                     | less than 10
```

Comment: Can we do the same comparisons for Strings. I tried but kept getting errors.

Comment: if (0 <= 10 && 10 <= 5) , how to compare this condition in drools decision table?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to give the part of the condition as a value. In the header you can give "**value $param**" to evaluate. (BTW to be able to enter values like == 10 you have to change the cell format to Text in Excel)

```
CONDITION                          |  ACTION
Example                            |
value $param                       |
-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------
== 10                              |  System.out.println("equals to 10")
in (10, 11)                        |  System.out.println("is 10 or 11")
> 10                               |  System.out.println("greater than 10")
< 10                               |  System.out.println("less than 10")
```

Comment: if (0 <= 10 && 10 <= 5) , how to compare this condition in drools decision table?

Answer (score 1):

You can take look at this

http://s11.postimage.org/oya6zxr83/Screenshot.png

here we take userlocation and count from user and check if count is less than initial count of each city and if condition satisfied the loop will run till Loop Condition.

Hope It will Be Helpful .

Comment: Could you move the content of your example into your answer? Linking the answer to external resources is not very helpful for the knowledge capture, that image might not be there in the future.

Comment: if (0 <= 10 && 10 <= 5) , how to compare this condition in drools decision table?